# build json response with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have tried to handle JSON responses with a complex structure and I don't know how to manage it after multiple attempts.

The JSON response must be like this:

```
"note": {
      "vote": 3,
      "items":[
        {
            "value": 1,
            "touchArea": {
                "x": 122,
                "y": 173,
                "w": 89,
                "h": 89
            }
        },
        {
            "value": 2,
            "touchArea": {
                "x": 122,
                "y": 283,
                "w": 89,
                "h": 89
            }
        },
        {
            "value": 3,
            "touchArea": {
                "x": 122,
                "y": 390,
                "w": 89,
                "h": 89
            }
        }
      ]
```

Note: 'vote' is the max value of the array

As source, i request MYSQL and i get this array ($touch) :

```
Array ( [0] => V:1,X:122,Y:173,W:89,H:89 [1] => V:2,X:122,Y:283,W:89,H:89 [2] => V:3,X:122,Y:390,W:89,H:89 )
```

My question is : How to generate this JSON response from PHP with loops, in this example we have only 3 values, but it could be more.

Comment: Is each element a string; e.g: `V:1,X:122,Y:173,W:89,H:89`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to edit and re-save your data from and to json file or string.

```
<?php
    $sInFile  = 'in2.json';
    $sOutFile = 'out2.json';

    $aDevelopers = array();
    $aArtists    = array();
    $aCooks      = array();

    $sRaw       = file_get_contents( $sInFile );
    var_dump( $sRaw );
    // object
    $oData    = json_decode( $sRaw );
    //array
    $aData    = json_decode( $sRaw, 1 );
    $aNote = $aData[ 'note' ];
    $aItems = $aNote[ 'items' ];
var_dump( $aData );
    $iCountData = count( $aItems );
    // Loops through items and set new values.
    for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountData; ++$i )
    {
        $aItem = $aItems[ $i ];
        $aItem[ 'value' ] = 'newvalue';
        $aItem[ 'touchArea' ][ 'x' ] = 3455;
        $aItem[ 'touchArea' ][ 'y' ] = 43;
        $aItems[ $i ] = $aItem;
    }
    $aNote[ 'items' ] = $aItems;
    $aData[ 'note' ] = $aNote;
var_dump( $aData );
    $sNewJson = json_encode( $aData );

    file_put_contents( $sOutFile, $sNewJson );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your result set from MySQL is an array of strings, as implied in your question, you'll need to iterate over this result set, split the string on `,` and then on `:`, before massaging the data into the structure you want, before finally converting to json.

The following should work for you given the information you have provided:

```
<?php

// your initial result set from mysql - an array of strings

$touch = [
    'V:1,X:122,Y:173,W:89,H:89',
    'V:2,X:122,Y:283,W:89,H:89',
    'V:3,X:122,Y:390,W:89,H:89',
];

// map over each element in your result set...

$items = array_map(function($item) {

    $array = [];

    // first, break each string on `,` to 
    // get an array of elements; e.g:
    // ['V:1', 'X:122', 'Y:173', 'W:89', 'H:89'] etc.

    $itemElements = explode(',', $item);

    // then, iterate over these elements...

    foreach ($itemElements as $itemElement) {
        // explode on `:` and assign as a key value pair
        list($key, $value) = explode(':', $itemElement);
        // then, check the key and add the 
        // value to the array as appropriate
        if ('V' === $key) {
            $array['value'] = $value;
        } else {
            $array['touchArea'][strtolower($key)] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $array;

}, $touch);

// then, build the `$note` array...

$note = [
    'note' => [
        'vote'  => count($items),
        'items' => $items,
    ]
];

// finally, json encode

echo json_encode($note, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This yields:

```
{
    "note": {
        "vote": 3,
        "items": [
            {
                "value": "1",
                "touchArea": {
                    "x": "122",
                    "y": "173",
                    "w": "89",
                    "h": "89"
                }
            },
            {
                "value": "2",
                "touchArea": {
                    "x": "122",
                    "y": "283",
                    "w": "89",
                    "h": "89"
                }
            },
            {
                "value": "3",
                "touchArea": {
                    "x": "122",
                    "y": "390",
                    "w": "89",
                    "h": "89"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `array_map`, `explode`, `array_column` and `max` functions:

```
$touch = ["V:1,X:122,Y:173,W:89,H:89", "V:2,X:122,Y:283,W:89,H:89", "V:3,X:122,Y:390,W:89,H:89"];

$result_arr = ["note" => ["vote" => 0, "items" => []]];  // basic structure

array_map(function($v) use (&$result_arr){
    $arr = explode(",", $v);
    $result = [];
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $new_arr = explode(":", $value);
        $key = strtolower($new_arr[0]);
        if ($key == "v"){
            $result["value"] = $new_arr[1];
        } else {
            $result["touchArea"][$key] = $new_arr[1];
        }
    }
    $result_arr["note"]["items"][] = $result;
}, $touch);

// getting max vote
$result_arr["note"]["vote"] = max(array_column($result_arr["note"]["items"], "value"));

$final_json = json_encode($result_arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thx for help. That will works with PHP5? Cause ie $result_arr = ["note" => ["vote" => 0, "items" => []]]; is not valid with PHP5

Comment: you have forgotten about the version. That piece of code is valid for PHP5 in general. As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax. Since PHP 5.5 you can use great function `array_column`. Upgrade today and "trim the sails to the wind". (We have PHP 7.0.4 already) (my code works without any problems)

Comment: Thx. It definitively helps!

Comment: Subs Question : final array is :

$appscreen_arr = array(
   "status" => 0, 
   "version" => 0, 
   "screens" => array(
      "veille" => array("background" => 0), 
      "note" => array("vote" => 0, "items" => array(), "background" => 0), 
      "tel" => 0,
      "fin" => 0)
      );

With you code and array_map, i just need replace $note_arr with this format?

Comment: $note_arr become $appscreen_arr.

Comment: if you have upgraded php version and ` $appscreen_arr ` is the main array - you can place `$result_arr` from my solution into "main" array: `$appscreen_arr['note']  = $result_arr['note']`